# Finding equivalence classes under permutation symmetry

Tags: combinatorics, symmetry, polya-counting-theory

If we write a 9 digit binary number as a $3\times3$ matrix, for example $101110101$ would be written as,
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 1\\\
                 1 & 1 & 0\\\
                 1 & 0 & 1
 \end{bmatrix}$$
We can take genral representation for any 9 digit binary string as follows, 
$$I = \begin{bmatrix}I_{00} & I_{01} & I_{02}\\\
                   I_{10} & I_{11} & I_{12}\\\
                   I_{20} & I_{21} & I_{22}
 \end{bmatrix}$$
**Now, If I put every number represented by permutations of the indices into the same set, then how many such sets would I have?**
To give an example, we apply permutation $\pi_{1,0,2}$ on $I$
$$\pi_{1,0,2}(I) = \begin{bmatrix}I_{11} & I_{10} & I_{12}\\\
                   I_{01} & I_{00} & I_{02}\\\
                   I_{21} & I_{20} & I_{22}
 \end{bmatrix}$$
A more specific example would be $111100001$ becomes $001010111$ by permutation (1,0,2).
So we have to essentially divide these $2^9$ numbers into $x$ sets, what is $x$ ?

Comment: Look up Burnside's Lemma and examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in a comment, you can count these equivalence classes using [Burnside’s lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma). There are $6$ symmetry elements. The identity leaves $2^9$ strings invariant. Each transposition leaves one entry of the matrix in place and swaps the other $8$ in pairs, and thus leaves $2^5$ strings invariant. Each $3$-cycle permutes the entries of the matrix in three $3$-cycles and thus leaves $2^3$ strings invariant. Thus the number of orbits under these permutations is

$$
\frac{2^9+3\cdot2^5+2\cdot2^3}{6}=104\;.
$$

Comment: Can you please explain, how 8 pairs invariant implies $2^5$ strings and 3-cycle implies $2^3$ strings invariant. I accepted the answer because it verified with my code. But I would like to know the inner working. I hope you could help.

Comment: @SagarM: Not $8$ pairs, but $8$ in pairs, that is, $4$ pairs, that is, $4$ $2$-cycles. Each entire cycle (fixed point, $2$-cycle or $3$-cycle) of the permutation must be filled with the same symbol for the string to be invariant under the permutation. So we have one independent binary choice (and thus one factor of $2$) for each cycle. $4$ pairs and one fixed point is $5$ cycles, so that makes $2^5$ invariant strings; and $3$ $3$-cycles is $3$ cycles, that makes $2^3$ invariant strings.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your comment taught me a lot.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3611773/142677