# Polya's Enumeration : Where am I going wrong?

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, symmetry, polya-counting-theory

If we write a 9 digit binary number as a $3\times3$ matrix, for example $101110101$ would be written as,
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 1\\\
                 1 & 1 & 0\\\
                 1 & 0 & 1
 \end{bmatrix}$$
We can take general representation for any 9 digit binary string as follows, 
$$I = \begin{bmatrix}I_{00} & I_{01} & I_{02}\\\
                   I_{10} & I_{11} & I_{12}\\\
                   I_{20} & I_{21} & I_{22}
 \end{bmatrix}$$
**Now, If I put every number represented by permutations of the indices into the same set, then how many such sets would I have?**
To give an example, we apply permutation $\pi_{1,0,2}$ on $I$
$$\pi_{1,0,2}(I) = \begin{bmatrix}I_{11} & I_{10} & I_{12}\\\
                   I_{01} & I_{00} & I_{02}\\\
                   I_{21} & I_{20} & I_{22}
 \end{bmatrix}$$
A more specific example would be $111100001$ becomes $001010111$ by permutation (1,0,2).
So we have to essentially divide these $2^9$ numbers into $x$ sets, what is $x$

---

So this question has been answered here [Finding equivalence classes under permutation symmetry](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3589845/142677). Now I wanted to answer this question using Polya's Enumeration. And I figured out the generating function to be $$\frac{x_1^3+3x_1x_2+2x_3}{6}$$
I am not clear as to what should I put the value of $x_i$ to be? It is definitely not 2, but then what?

Comment: How did you get $$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1\\\
                 1 & 1 & 0\\\
                 1 & 0 & 1
 \end{bmatrix}$$ from $101110101$?

Comment: @Shaun a typo. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: The answer in the other question you asked and linked to contains that formula all filled out. I'm not sure what else you are asking.

Comment: @JoshB. so the question in link solves the problem with Burnside's theorem. Whereas now I want to solve the same problem using a much-related method of Polya's enumeration. In this case, all $x_i$ have to be replaced with one unique value(at least in my understanding), and if you take this into account then the generating function is fundamentally different from the expression from burnside, and they must agree on the end result but they don't have to agree semanticaly.

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong cycle index.  If we analyze the structure of the group in terms of its effects on the 3 by 3 array, there are

- $1$ permutation that leaves all $9$ elements fixed,
- $3$ permutations that have $4$ cycles of length $2$ and leave $1$ element fixed, and
- $2$ permutations that have $3$ cycles of length $3$.

So the cycle index is
$$Z = \frac{1}{6} (x_1^9 + 3 x_1 x_2^4 + 3 x_3^3)$$
The figure inventory, since there are $2$ binary digits, is $x+y$.  If we "substitute" the figure inventory into the cycle index, the result is
$$f(x,y) = \frac{1}{6} [ (x+y)^9 + 3(x+y)(x^2 + y^2)^4 + 2 (x^3+y^3)^3 ]
$$
The significance of $f$ is that if we want to know the number of distinct arrays with $3$ zeroes and $6$ ones, for example, it is the coefficient of $x^3 y^6$ when $f$ is expanded.  But if we want to know the count of all the possibilities, we can simply let $x=y=1$, with the result
$$f(1,1) = \frac{1}{6}[2^9 + 3(2)2^4 = 2(2^3)] = \boxed{104}$$